# objective c array of booleans

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am working on a game that will have a two dimensional board of dots, each with one boolean attribute (occupied/not occupied). I was thinking the best way to accomplish this is to create a simple c array of Booleans. This will be much more efficient than creating a mutablearray. I'm just confused the best way to accomplish this. The trouble is that I don't know the size of the board until I initialize the board object. 
The interface looks like this:

```
@interface TouchBoard : NSObject{
NSInteger height,width;
BOOL dots[10][10];

}
```

And the implementation like this:

```
-(id)initWithHeight:(NSInteger)rows Width:(NSInteger)columns{
    if ( self = [super init]){
        height = rows;
        width = columns;
        dots[height][width];
    }
    return self;

}
```

Trouble is, in the interface, if i try to declare the dots variable with a dynamic number of indices, dots[][], it'll just give me an error.
Obviously I don't know the size of the array until the object is initialized, but after that it's not going to be changing and only its elements will be changing from true/false.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Use `malloc` to dynamically allocate memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your interface, declares:

```
BOOL ** dots;
```

Then, you'll need to use `malloc`, to dynamically allocate memory:

```
int i;

dots = malloc( rows * sizeof( BOOL * ) );

for( i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
{
    dots[ i ] = calloc( columns, sizeof( BOOL ) );
}
```

Don't forget to free in your dealloc method:

```
int i;

for( i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
{
    free( dots[ i ] );
}

free( dots );
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can just do: `dots = malloc(rows * columns * sizeof(BOOL));`

Comment: how does this work with ARC? i assume I still need to put this in the dealloc method right?

Comment: Right. No problem with ARC unless you call super dealloc.